# CSS vertical alignment in table columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically align text in two table columns, one of which also has a text input control. Basic code such as:

```
<td>Caption</td><td>Enter here <input type="text"></td>
```

No matter how I apply vertical-align to one or both columns, 'Caption' is not on the same level as 'Enter here'. Most times 'Caption' is higher. What's the solution?

Comment: usually content is vertically aligned in the middle by default in tables so we would have to see your html/css code to see what is happening - possibly different font sizes...different padding applied or other...

Comment: try `td { vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: Looks like "Caption" and "Enter here" are both vertically aligned on the center line of the text box.  I'm not sure I know what you're wanting.  Do you want them to be aligned by the bottom?  Or the top?  Alignment to the vertical center of the box is what I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
td, input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If that doesn't work, you will need to post more code to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that Caption and Enter here are not vertically aligned, despite using the suggested 'vertical-align: middle;' you may have to look into giving the columns a specific or minimum width. I am suspecting that the elements may not be perfectly positioned visually next to each other on the 'reading' level, due to the columns adjusting with top/bottom padding in order to maintain vertical alignment. Therefore being strict about the width of your columns may help.

However I agree with @willoller, if this on top of what the rest of the community suggested isn't working for you, then you need to post relevant code that will help us pinpoint an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

It should vertical align to middle by default assuming there isn't some other CSS being applied. ... your issue might be related to line height where text and inputs aren't the same .. ..try:

```
td{
  line-height:40px;
  height:40px;
}
```

Comment: I've posted a further response with some code, but it's appeared as another 'answer'. My apologies. Any further help based on that 'answer' would be appreciated.

Comment: @user1342299  .. now that the alignment issue is fixed, try reducing the height/line-height down to 25px or 20 px until the inter-row spacing is as you want.  since the height is 40px, it is creating what looks to be padding or margin above and below, but that really is the height of the table row now. .. so try line-height:25px;height:25px; first, then increase/decrease based on desired look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help so far. The line-height and height additions correct the vertical alignment of the two texts, but also significantly increase the inter-row spacing. This doesn't improve if I set the margin, padding and border to 0. I can't reduce the heights to less than 40px or the alignment fails again.

The following code demonstrates the problems. There's a demo page at www.quinze.co.uk/test/test.html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Table test</title>       
<style type="text/css">
.s0 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.s1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
.s2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;</pre>
    Col1 captions have different vertical alignment to Col2 but inter-row spacing is good.
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="s0">Col1</td>
        <td class="s0">Col2<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s0">Col1</td>
        <td class="s0">Col2<input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" value="ABC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s0">Col1</td>
        <td class="s0">Col2<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>    
<pre>   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
</pre>  
    The two column captions are now at the same height but the inter-row spacing has increased
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="s1">Col1</td>
        <td class="s1">Col2<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s1">Col1</td>
        <td class="s1">Col2<input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" value="ABC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s1">Col1</td>
        <td class="s1">Col2<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>    
<pre>   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 0;
</pre>
Padding, margins and border reduced to 0 but still greater inter-row spacing
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="s2">Col1</td>
        <td class="s2">Col2<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s2">Col1</td>
        <td class="s2">Col2<input type="checkbox" checked><input type="text" value="ABC"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="s2">Col1</td>
        <td class="s2">Col2<input type="text"></td>
    </tr>   
</table>    

</body>
</html>
```